# Error while trying to fit oridinal encoder object to snowflake table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to perform some preprocessing on some data stored in a `snowflake.snowpark.table.Table` object named `diamonds_df`. However when I try to fit the `OrdinalEncoder` object to `diamonds_df`, I get the following error-
`SnowparkSQLException: (1300) (1304): 01b30087-0000-43da-0000-0000290963dd: 090105 (22000): 01b30087-0000-43da-0000-0000290963dd: Cannot perform CREATE TEMPTABLE. This session does not have a current database. Call 'USE DATABASE', or use a qualified name.` I assume that the fit method takes in the snowpark equivalent of pandas dataframe which I believe is `snowflake.snowpark.dataframe` however the [docs](https://https:/https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/latest/api/snowflake.snowpark.DataFrame#snowflake.snowpark.DataFrame)
suggest that `snowflake.snowpark.table.Table` extends `snowflake.snowpark.dataframe`.

```
categories = {
    "CUT": np.array(["IDEAL", "PREMIUM", "VERY_GOOD", "GOOD", "FAIR"]),
    "CLARITY": np.array(["IF", "VVS1", "VVS2", "VS1", "VS2", "SI1", "SI2", "I1", "I2", "I3"]),
    "COLOR": np.array(['D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J']),
}
snowml_oe = snowml.OrdinalEncoder(input_cols=["CUT", "CLARITY", "COLOR"], 
                                    output_cols=["CUT_OE", "CLARITY_OE","COLOR_OE"], 
                                    categories=categories)
                               
                               
snowml_oe.fit(diamonds_df)

snowml_oe.transform(diamonds_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that your connection to Snowflake has not indicated what database it's using within Snowflake (Snowpark needs it here to create a temporary table).

This configuration can be a default database/schema for the user that is connecting, or you can set it manually.

This will show you what's the current database/schema:

```py
session.get_fully_qualified_current_schema()
# https://github.com/Snowflake-Labs/sfguide-getting-started-machine-learning/blob/main/hol/1_3_DEMO_full_data_exploration_transformation.ipynb
```

Likewise you'll need a warehouse for computing.

I would comment more on how to set this in your code, but you didn't share the relevant part of your code to do this.